# Is it possible to programmatically determine if a MySQL column has a default set?

Tags: mysql

According to the [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-infoschema-excerpt/8.3/en/information-schema-columns-table.html), `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.COLUMN_DEFAULT` is `NULL` in two different scenarios:

> The default value for the column. This is NULL if the column has an explicit default of NULL, or if the column definition includes no DEFAULT clause.

That implies that this column's value does not provide enough information to differentiate between an explicit default of NULL and if a column definition includes no DEFAULT clause.

**Is there an alterative mechanism to differentiate between these two cases?**

I'm aware that you can see this in `show create table` output, but that is not designed for machine consumption.

Comment: Not as far as I know. There have been bugs filed on this, e.g. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=33716

Comment: My guess is that the information is buried in the internal data dictionary, but there is no direct access to that info via information_schema.